# count in loop unnecessary input win32 API

Tags: c, winapi

I have a coding logic problem but I can't understand the reason for the error.

I made a simple input function in C for the input system with the win32 API,

the function has two parameters one for the keyboard's hexadecimal code and parameter 2 is for the key mode.

the key modes are ,
`SINGLE`: to activate the command only once and only activate again if pressed again.

`KEEP`: in an infinite loop of the key triggering the sudden command.

and the problematic part,

`KEEP_TIME`: it counts how long the button was pressed in milliseconds.

```
#define PRESS_STATE 0x8000

typedef enum 
{
    SINGLE,
    KEEP,
    KEEP_TIME
} InputMode;


static DWORD keyInput(int keyCode, InputMode mode) 
{
    static bool_ keyState[256] = { FALSE };  /* Array to control the state of the keys */
    static bool_ prevKeyState[256] = { FALSE }; /* Array to store the previous state of keys */
    static DWORD keyPressTimes[256] = { 0 }; /* Array to record key press times */
    DWORD releaseTime = 0;
    DWORD pressTime = 0;
    DWORD pressDuration = 0;

    /* Get current key state */
    bool_ currentKeyState = GetAsyncKeyState(keyCode) & PRESS_STATE;

    /* Check if the key is pressed at the current time */
    if (currentKeyState) 
    {
        /* Check if the key was released in the previous frame */
        if (!prevKeyState[keyCode]) 
        {
            /* Mark the key as pressed in the current frame */
            keyState[keyCode] = true;
            keyPressTimes[keyCode] = GetTickCount(); /* Records key press time */
            prevKeyState[keyCode] = true;

            if (mode == SINGLE) 
            {
               return true;
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (keyState[keyCode]) 
        {
            prevKeyState[keyCode] = FALSE; /* Mark the key as released in the current frame */

            if (mode == SINGLE) 
            {
                keyState[keyCode] = FALSE;
            }

            releaseTime = GetTickCount();
            pressTime = keyPressTimes[keyCode];
            pressDuration = releaseTime - pressTime;

           if (mode == KEEP_TIME) 
            {
                return pressDuration;
                keyState[keyCode] = false;
            }            

        }
    }

    /* Return 0 if KEEP mode is used and the key is pressed */
    return (mode == KEEP) && currentKeyState ? 1 : 0;
}
```

the code is in the ANSI C89 standard.

The problem with `KEEP_TIME` mode is that it returns the correct value in ms, but it starts counting infinitely after the number entered.

```
KEY : 'W' pressed by 422 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 437 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 453 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 469 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 484 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 500 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 516 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 531 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 547 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 562 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 578 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 594 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 609 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 625 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 641 ms
KEY : 'W' pressed by 656 ms
```

and so on, but I don't know the reason for the count, I don't know if it's because of the loop or because `printf()` is inside the loop.

here is the code inside the loop.

```
void GLRender()
{/* GAME LOOP */
    
    DWORD pressDuration = keyInput(KEY_W, KEEP_TIME);

    if (pressDuration > 1) 
    {
            /* Print key press time */
            printf("KEY : '%c' pressed by %d ms\n", KEY_W, pressDuration);
    }
}
```

I wanted to make the third mode KEEP_TIME return the value in correct milliseconds so I can do a time button system

Comment: Why are you asking for the *asynchronous* key state rather than the *synchronous* key state? Indeed, why are you polling at all?

Comment: It's because I'm making a graphics engine for weaker computers, and I've already suffered with the operating system being overloaded with tasks, and when this happens, GetKeyState() is executed in a slow queue of events, even though it's almost unnoticeable, it's a little boring.

Comment: keyState[keyCode] = false; after return is never reached.

Comment: `GetKeyState()` is faster than `GetAsyncKeyState()`. If performance is a concern, don't go with an inherently slower solution.

Comment: @PHIKILL Also, `GetKeyboardState()` is another option.